# Phone conversation diarization with LIUM

Tags: speech-processing, speech

I am trying split call-center recording by speakers. [LIUM](http://lium3.univ-lemans.fr/diarization/doku.php/overview) seems to fit great. But results look random to me (green is etalon, gray is what I get):
[image: diarization result]
So I think I am doing something wrong. Maybe features are not extracted correctly? Command I am running is

```
java -cp lium_spkdiarization-8.4.1.jar fr.lium.spkDiarization.system.Telephone \
     --saveAllStep --doCEClustering \
     --fInputMask sound.wav --sOutputMask=%s.xml \
     --sOutputFormat=seg.xml,UTF8 sound
```

sound.wav is `RIFF (little-endian) data, WAVE audio, Microsoft PCM, 16 bit, mono 48000 Hz`. One can download it here https://yadi.sk/d/w0doqi7QhcjJj . Please, help!

Comment: I am also doing something similar. But LIUM toolkit gives me more than 2 speakers. I would like to clarify on your statement that you joined all other clusters and represented it as 2nd speaker. how did you do that? Can you explain more on that? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`system.Telephone` is just for detection of speech, that's why you get only init clusters.  You can use default `fr.lium.spkDiarization.system.Diarization` it will do proper steps as described in [LIUM docs](http://www-lium.univ-lemans.fr/diarization/doku.php/single-show_diarization), result will be like this:

```
;; cluster S0
file 1 0 1135 M S U S0
file 1 5722 300 M S U S0
file 1 9266 359 M S U S0
file 1 12670 370 M S U S0
;; cluster S1
file 1 1135 832 F S U S1
file 1 5372 350 F S U S1
file 1 6022 572 F S U S1
file 1 10167 1550 F S U S1
file 1 13040 466 F S U S1
file 1 13623 352 F S U S1
;; cluster S10 [ merge HCLR 0 = S10 in S11 with 1.208107727685253 ]
file 1 1967 693 F S U S10
file 1 2660 1644 F S U S10
file 1 4304 1068 F S U S10
file 1 6594 937 F S U S10
;; cluster S12
file 1 7531 429 F S U S12
file 1 8692 574 F S U S12
;; cluster S13
file 1 7960 732 M T U S13
;; cluster S16
file 1 9625 542 F S U S16
file 1 11717 953 F S U S16
```

LIUM models included into jar are trained for 16khz, so the input should be better 16khz, you need to resample your 48khz file to 16khz before you feed into LIUM.

If you want to run on telephone speech, you might need to retrain mail/female/ubm models for that. It is also worth to note that LIUM models are trained for French, for other languages they should be better retrained.

Overall, LIUM is not expected to work out of box, you might need to spend some time to make it work properly.

Comment: Thank you. Sure, first of all I tried command described in docs and got results that you showed. But they also look pretty random to me (maybe a bit better) https://yadi.sk/i/_fW4BDxChdMgx . You think this is the best I can get without retraining?

Comment: On second picture you have s0 and s1 swapped in the reference, actually its the other way around and it was able to catch quite many things properly. It does not handle quick turns of the speakers though, it was not designed to do that. It works best on TV shows where you have one turn in a minute. The default setting for small initial segmentation (MSeg step) is set to 2.5s, so it did not detect the turn of speakers in the fist 11 seconds. Silence model also did not work properly and instead of silence you got speaker S10. So it needs some work of course.

Comment: For example if you add in MSeg step in above script `--sModelWindowSize=100 --sMinimumWindowSize=100` it will be able to catch initial segments properly 

`;; cluster S0
file 1 0 204 F S U S0
file 1 1350 175 F S U S0
;; cluster S1
file 1 204 943 M S U S1`

Comment: Yes, it is much better https://yadi.sk/i/0WrwRQEvhdSAf . Now I need to make it detect silence and produce just two clusters. Thank you

Comment: Ok, I gave up trying to detect silence using LIUM, I think I'll do it manually in python. But I have to cluster my segments in two speakers any way. So the best segmentation that I have is https://yadi.sk/i/V8v_aSZphexBm . But  there are too many speakers.

Comment: So I do `java -cp lium_spkdiarization-8.4.1.jar fr.lium.spkDiarization.programs.MClust --sInputMask=sound.xml.adj.seg --sInputFormat=seg.xml,UTF8 --fInputMask=sound2.wav --fInputDesc=audio16kHz2sphinx,1:3:2:0:0:0,13,1:1:300:4 --cMethod=ce --cThr=100 --tInputMask=ubm.gmm --emCtrl=1,5,0.01 --sTop=5,ubm.gmm --cMinimumOfCluster=2 --sOutputMask=sound.xml.c.seg --sOutputFormat=seg.xml,UTF8 sound` and get two speakers https://yadi.sk/i/KWh4UNKOhexUv . But they totally do not match my reference markup.

Comment: I thought, maybe their `ubm.gmm` does not fit my recording. So I trained my own `java -cp lium_spkdiarization-8.4.1.jar fr.lium.spkDiarization.programs.MTrainInit --sInputMask=../segments/rigla_etalon.xml --sInputFormat=seg.xml,UTF8 --fInputMask=sound2.wav --fInputDesc=audio16kHz2sphinx,1:3:2:0:0:0,13,1:1:300:4 --kind=DIAG --nbComp=8 --emInitMethod=split_all --emCtrl=1,5,0.05 --tOutputMask=ubm2_init.gmm sound`

Comment: `java -cp lium_spkdiarization-8.4.1.jar fr.lium.spkDiarization.programs.MTrainEM --sInputMask=../segments/rigla_etalon.xml --sInputFormat=seg.xml,UTF8 --fInputMask=sound2.wav --fInputDesc=audio16kHz2sphinx,1:3:2:0:0:0,13,1:1:300:4 --emCtrl=1,20,0.01 --tInputMask=ubm2_init.gmm --tOutputMask=ubm2.gmm sound` . But the result was even worse https://yadi.sk/i/tMdKDDQUhexiC . If I am doing something completely wrong please point it to me

Comment: --cThr=100 in your script looks very high, in the original script in CLR step the threshold is 1.7. http://www-lium.univ-lemans.fr/diarization/doku.php/single-show_diarization

Comment: I did it intentionally so that the number of output clusters is exactly 2

Comment: I'm not sure what are you running, with the script above I get 3 clusters by default. You can get my folder here: http://alphacephei.com/other/spk-demo.tar.gz

Comment: Thank you! It seems like I have some ok results. I did two additional manual steps. Removed silence segments by hand by threshold. Since number of clusters was not always = 2, I did one more "genius" transformation to LIUM output. Cluster with longest total time is first speaker. All other clusters are joined and represent second speaker! It did not work with my initial example https://yadi.sk/i/B8_AdTvEhgeLa , but other examples worked out ok https://yadi.sk/i/6fD9suwXhgeMR https://yadi.sk/i/qJS5ai3ohgeMs https://yadi.sk/i/3dKkVNibhgeNJ https://yadi.sk/i/_u4kfyi1hgeNa Thank you, Nikolay!

Comment: If all other steps work out as I expect maybe I should understand how all this LIUM toolchain operates and come up with some more robust solution. Maybe you can suggest some good reading that helps to understand LIUM? Just source code does help much.